# Where can I ask questions about my undergraduate math career?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is there a subforum on StackExchange specifically for math students who have questions about course suggestions, preparation for grad school, etc.?

Comment: Vacuously the answer is no, because there is no concept of "subforum" on StackExchange websites (not outside of StackOverflow, anyway).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not even there; facebook.SO experiment was [shut down last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186850/251274).

Comment: you can ask them anywhere. They'll get closed, but, if your lucky someone may answer them before they get censored for a technicality of website organization. There exist users here and elsewhere who care more about helping you than maintaining a neat and tidy site definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: it came to my attention that graduate admissions [are on topic at Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions+mathematics?page=1&sort=votes&pagesize=15). See in particular

- [Path to a good grad school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10334)
- [Acceptance into graduate math programs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8040)
- [What advice would you give students applying for graduate school in mathematics?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16526)

---

At present, there is no SE site for undergraduate math career advice. As you probably noticed, [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is for graduate school and above.

There is a proposal for a site [Higher Education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52024/higher-education):

> Proposed Q&A site for questions related to higher education, high school, college and grad school admissions including preparation of standardized tests like GRE, SAT.

The proposal hasn't had much support yet. It's still in the "definition" stage, 11 months after creation. And the example questions appear to be mostly of "preparation for  standardized tests" variety.

---

One issue is that suggestions of courses to take will be specific to your institution, and preparations for graduate study  is something that should be tailored to *your* strengths and weaknesses. An SE site can't replace an academic advisor (I presume you have one).

Comment: As I understand it, Mathematics Learning, Studying, and Education is intended to be aimed at teachers and not at students.  (There is actually a call to have the name changed to reflect this aim.)  I think that questions such as the ones the OP proposes will not be welcome there.

Comment: The issue is I attend an extremely small, low-ranked, no-name school and the faculty here don't seem to make any effort at all when I try to reach out to them for advice. I am unsure of what other options I may have in regards to getting into a decent grad school from a very poor undergrad standpoint.

Comment: Going from small, no-name, undergrad school to good graduate school in math?  Graduate Record Exam.

Comment: @user130018 See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this site may be helpful to you, if you don't know it already:  http://www.mathematicsgre.com/